# How to use PathFigure from resources in PathGeometry?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, pathgeometry

I wonder whether is there any way to use a `PathFigure` from resources in `PathGeometry` element in xaml. Let's say I have a ResourceDictionary and a two `PathFigure` objects inside it with the 'x:Key' attributes equal to "Figure1" and "Figure2" respectively. 
My goal is to create a `PathGeometry` with `Figures` property filled with a collection containing Figure1 and Figure2. I can do it so easily with a code behind file, however I would like to know is there any way to do it with xaml only.

```
<PathFigure IsClosed="True" StartPoint="2,9" x:Key="Figure1">
    <ArcSegment Point="15,9" Size="6.5, 2"/>
    <LineSegment Point="15,12"/>
    <ArcSegment Point="2,12" Size="6.5, 2"/>
</PathFigure>

<PathFigure IsClosed="True" StartPoint="10,7" x:Key="Figure2">
    <LineSegment Point="10, 2"/>
    <LineSegment Point="13,2"/>
    <LineSegment Point="13,7"/>
    <ArcSegment Point="10,7" Size="2,2" IsLargeArc="True"/>
</PathFigure>
```

I can create now a `PathGeometry` :

```
<PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" x:Key="1">
    <PathFigureCollection>
        //Here I want to put Figure1 and Figure2
    </PathFigureCollection>
</PathGeometry>
```

I think I can write some kind of `MarkupExtension` to do the following, but I am looking for the best way.
Thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need anything special just the already built-in `StaticResourceExtension` class (markup extension).

```
<Window.Resources>
    <PathFigure IsClosed="True" StartPoint="2,9" x:Key="Figure1">
        <ArcSegment Point="15,9" Size="6.5, 2"/>
        <LineSegment Point="15,12"/>
        <ArcSegment Point="2,12" Size="6.5, 2"/>
    </PathFigure>

    <PathFigure IsClosed="True" StartPoint="10,7" x:Key="Figure2">
        <LineSegment Point="10, 2"/>
        <LineSegment Point="13,2"/>
        <LineSegment Point="13,7"/>
        <ArcSegment Point="10,7" Size="2,2" IsLargeArc="True"/>
    </PathFigure>

    <PathGeometry FillRule="Nonzero" x:Key="OneAndTwo">
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="Figure1" />
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="Figure2" />
    </PathGeometry>
</Window.Resources>
```

Usage:

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Data="{StaticResource OneAndTwo}" />
```

Comment: Exactly what I need! I haven't considered using StaticResource markup extension in this way. Thank you :)